# How to detect a Dictionary included a subDictionary or not?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I declared a static mainDict like this,

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> mainDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, object> aSubDict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
mainDict.Add("StringA0Key", "StringValue");
mainDict.Add("StringA1Key", aSubDict);
```

How to detect the Value Type is a string(StringValue) or dictionary(aSubDict)

I need to detect the value type and loop into "aSubDict", otherwise i just print the "StringValue". thank you.

[updated]

Thanks for your help, i closed my question with the updatd code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> mainDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public static void Main()
    {


        Dictionary<string, object> aSubDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        mainDict.Add("sA0Key", "sA0Value");
        mainDict.Add("sA1Key", aSubDict);         
        aSubDict.Add("sSubKey","sSubValue");

        foreach (string theKey in mainDict.Keys)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, mainDict[theKey]) && (mainDict[theKey] is Dictionary<string, object>))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("type of aSubDict");
                foreach (string subKey in aSubDict.Keys)
                {
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(null,aSubDict[subKey]) && aSubDict[subKey] is Dictionary<string, object>)
                    {    
                        Console.WriteLine("type of Child Dict");
                    }
                    else if (!ReferenceEquals(null, aSubDict[subKey]) && (aSubDict[subKey] is string))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("subKey = {0}, subValue = {1}", subKey, aSubDict[subKey]);
                    }
                }

            }
            else if (!ReferenceEquals(null, mainDict[theKey]) &&  (mainDict[theKey] is string))
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("type string");
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", theKey, mainDict[theKey]);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to detect if the ***Value*** of a given dictionary KevValue pair in mainDict **is of the *exact Type*** of aSubDict : i.e. : a Dictionary whose keys are Type string, and values are Type object :

```
    Type testType = aSubDict.GetType();

    foreach (string theKey in mainDict.Keys)
    {
        if ((mainDict[theKey]).GetType() == testType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found");
        }
    }
```

If your goal is to detect if the ***Value*** of a given dictionary KevValue pair in mainDict ***is the instance*** aSubDict :

```
    foreach (string theKey in mainDict.Keys)
    {
        if (mainDict[theKey] == aSubDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found");
        }
    }
```

Let's round this out with a complete example that filters on 'Type only and does not use GetType() :

```
    foreach (string theKey in mainDict.Keys)
    {
        if(mainDict[theKey] is Dictionary<string, object>)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type of aSubDict");

        } else if (mainDict[theKey] is string)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type string");
        }
    }
```

All code above tested in Visual Studio Beta 2010 beta 2 compiled against FrameWork 3.5 (not the "client mode" 3.5, the full monte).

Answer (score 4):

```
if (obj is IDictionary)
```

This is because all Dictionaries, even if generic, [implement the IDictionary interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

*Also watch out for [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).*

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(null, obj) && obj is IDictionary)
```

**update**

You test for `is IDictionary<string, object>`. Possibly the sub-dictionary is different by Type Parameters like `IDictionary<int,string>` or any number of combinations of key/value Types - this means it's a different Type to the compiler. However if you want to treat it as a loosley-typed dictionary then just test for `is IDictionary` and use the [IDictionary members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary_members.aspx) - note those members take object references.

`Dictionary<string, int>` is not the same type as `Dictionary<int, object>` (They can never be the same type). However both are of the implemented type `IDictionary` - this is why IDictionary might be what you're searching for in this scenario.

I've taken the middle section of your code upate and modified it for IDictionary, although I haven't tested the logic or tried compiling it...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

...

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(null, kvp) && (kvp is IDictionary))
        {

            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in aSubDict)
            {
                if (entry.Value is IDictionary)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("iDictionary found");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SubKey = {0}, SubValue = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }
```

Likely you'll need to modify the logic because the sub-dictionary is either in the .Key or or .Value of the 'parent' dictionary entry, but this is a start.

Comment: Although I'd use ((obj != null) && (obj is IDictionary)) as I find this more readable.

Comment: @jdk and Paulo, I updated my post, i still can't understand all your suggestion. Would you please give more details about my code above. Thanks.

Comment: I provided a speculative update. Is that going in the right direction for your requirements?

Comment: ...and I included the IDictionary members in your code sample by copying & pasting here.

Comment: Please also see Gabriel's answer (below) to keep in mind that if you want to use "is IDictionary" instead of "is IDictionary<string, object>" you will need to be sure your project contains a reference to System.Collections.

Comment: @Billw, Sure,I would remember it in mind. btw, i noticed that the LOOP expression changed from "foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair1 in mainDict)" to "foreach (string theKey in mainDict.Keys)" @jdk. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check that it implements the interface [System.Collections.IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx)

```
if (mainDict["StringA1Key"] is IDictionary)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could i detect "if (mainDict[1].Value is IDictionary)" ?

Comment: @Nano: Check my modified answer. This is how to check the type

Comment: @Bill:  1.  I fixed the index thing.  I was not thinking.  2.  IDictionary is not the one from the Generics namespace, it is the one from the System.Collections namespace.  I modified my answer to reflect this as well.

Comment: @Gabriel Negative vote on your answer deleted. Comment removed. Thanks for correcting. "All's well that ends well." Shakespeare.